# Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: vba, excel

The following snippet of VBA code attempts a simple If statement over on an excel column of approx 80k rows long. The following error occurs.

Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)':
Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed

What is going wrong here?

```
Dim r As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To lastrow
    If InStr(Range("I" & r).Text, "WH") Then
        Range("Z" & r).Value = "O"
    ElseIf InStr(Range("I" & r).Text, "MOD") Then
        Range("Z" & r).Value = "M"
    ElseIf InStr(Range("I" & r).Text, "VER") Then
        Range("Z" & r).Value = "V"
    ElseIf InStr(Range("I" & r).Text, "WT") Then
        Range("Z" & r).Value = "WT"
    ElseIf InStr(Range("E" & r).Text, "OIL") Then
        Range("Z" & r).Value = "OIL"
    Else: Range("Z" & r).Value = "N"
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?  Instead of using `.Text`, do you get the same error with `.Value`?

Comment: I think more detail is needed. This code works in the simple test I did (no errors).

Comment: Might want to consider `case` statement.

Comment: Is the active sheet the one you are searching? What is the value of `r` when you get the error?

Comment: Is InStr actually needed? Is MOD, VER, OIL, etc. the whole cell or just part of a longer string within the cell?

Comment: What's the idea behind your `If` statements? I see you're trying to see if some text ("MOD","WH", etc) is in anywhere in the cell `Range(I & [row])`?

Comment: Apologies about the late reply. The program seems to go into an infinite loop and "whites out". To me, this is likely an indication that lastrow is on the order of about 80,000. 
The active sheet is the one being searched. The program times out before I can locate the variable r. 
MOD, VER, OIL, etc. are values that will be placed in a cell if the criteria are met. They can be changed to Tom, Dick and Harry for all that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA environments are not immune to instability. If you have had multiple crashes, save your work and restart your machine (cold boot).

With that said, each of these routines runs in less than a half-second as opposed to the 27 seconds that your original took to get through 80K cells.

```
Sub oilWT2()
    Dim r As Long, vVALs As Variant

    Debug.Print Timer
    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        vVALs = .Range(.Cells(2, "I"), .Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)).Value2
        For r = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            Select Case UCase(vVALs(r, 1))
                Case "WH"
                    vVALs(r, 1) = "O"
                Case "MOD", "VER"
                    vVALs(r, 1) = Right(vVALs(r, 1), 1)
                Case "WT", "OIL"
                    'do nothing - value already correct
                Case Else
                    vVALs(r, 1) = "N"
            End Select
        Next r
        .Cells(2, "Z").Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), 1) = vVALs
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub

Sub oilWT3()
    Dim r As Long, vVALs As Variant

    Debug.Print Timer
    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
        vVALs = .Range(.Cells(2, "I"), .Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)).Value2
        For r = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            Select Case True
                Case CBool(InStr(1, vVALs(r, 1), "WH", vbTextCompare))
                    vVALs(r, 1) = "O"
                Case CBool(InStr(1, vVALs(r, 1), "MOD", vbTextCompare)) Or _
                     CBool(InStr(1, vVALs(r, 1), "VER", vbTextCompare))
                    vVALs(r, 1) = Right(vVALs(r, 1), 1)
                Case CBool(InStr(1, vVALs(r, 1), "WT", vbTextCompare))
                    vVALs(r, 1) = "WT"
                Case CBool(InStr(1, vVALs(r, 1), "OIL", vbTextCompare))
                    vVALs(r, 1) = "OIL"
                Case Else
                    vVALs(r, 1) = "N"
            End Select
        Next r
        .Cells(2, "Z").Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), 1) = vVALs
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

The former simply looks at the entire cell contents; the latter uses the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx) to search for a string-within-a-string as your original does. By reusing a variant array to store the new values, it makes the conditional statements more efficient than a cell-by-cell read. The values are similarly returned *en masse* to column Z.

Answer (score 0):

When I received this error, it was because I had created an infinite loop, for example, a Worksheet_Change Sub set the value of a Range, creating another change. Double check what is triggering these Subs and ensure that the Sub will not infinitely trigger itself.